# Java Merge sort algorithm: What makes merge method run recursively on bigger sets of elements once initial singleton elements merge is done?

Tags: java, sorting, merge

Basically everything is in the question itself, I got a bit of code that runs alright but the logic of which is not completely clear to me.

To put it in more detail:

Analyzing an implementation of Merge sort I came to a conceptual question of what exactly is a statement that makes merge sort applications continue their merging once they merged the initial set of items (two singleton elements)?

As for now I see nothing that could prevent the program from just stopping the execution immediately after this first merge. What is that orders the application to continue?

Some pseudocode for illustration:

```
1. divideMethod
    {
    return the array 
    if the it has less than 2 elements

    { divide into 2 parts,
    divide (1st recursion) on the left half,
    divide (1st recursion)  on the right half,

    mergeMethod(so-called 2nd or inversed recursion) on left and right   halves,
    return the array
    }   
    } 
2. mergeMethod
```

*I did not paste the original code to keep the illustration as concise as possible.*

To prevent any misunderstandings, the principle of Merge sort is clear to me:

1 - **Divide** an array(or any other set of variables) into couples of singleton elements,

2 - **Compare and merge** these elements and then

3 - **Recompose** back the array while comparing bigger pre-ordered sets of elements.

But once the division to singleton elements and primary merge sort (sorting done in couples) are done, I don’t see what makes the code repeat the merge again and bring back all these small pairs into bigger ones (of 4, 8, 16 items and so on) to finally make up a full sorted array.

Where does this sort of a second (inverse) recursion come from, the first one being (as I described above) a division of the initial array?

The algorithm is implemented in Java but this question is evidently not specific to any particular programming language.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a question with the recursion.

```
divideMethod
    {
    return the array 
    if the it has less than 2 elements

    { divide into 2 parts,
    divide (1st recursion) on the left half,
    divide (1st recursion)  on the right half,
```

Creates a deep call stack. When the inner divide is called, the outer divide *isn't done*. It still has *its* merge to do. And the divide outside that has *its* merge to do.

As always, step through with a debugger (comes built in with IDEs such as Eclipse) and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Eclipse does actions behind the scenes, **I already debugged** the code before asking my question here... and debugger showed the behavior you're describing. But the thing is that debugger left **no indication regarding outer merge unfinished status**  :(... no mention like 'the line is pending' or any other sign of that type. When the time came to treat this **deep call stack**, as you call it, debugger did nothing but **simply jumped one step back**. And this absence of tracing created a confusion. Anyways, thanks again, your explanation is helpful.

Comment: The stack isn't all that deep, it's log2(n). For n = 1 million, that's 20 levels. For the debugger, use the step into feature. The "jump back" is probably a result of the return.

Comment: @rcgldr "deep" should be interpreted relative to the OP's initial misconception of "nothing at all."

Comment: The stack will have log2(n) levels of recursion. For n = 1 million, that's 20 levels. For the debugger, use the step into feature. The "jump back" is probably a result of the return.

Comment: @djechlin - deleted my prior comment, added a new one, will delete this comment later.

Comment: Before asking my question **I well  used 'step into' and 'step over'** functions **from** Eclipse **debugger**, of course with high-lighting **it traces every application's step** one by one, **but** (as stated above) once divide recursion continues for second and more time the **debugger never ever leaves any sign** letting know that the line is not finished and shall be **return** to.

Comment: @TomateFraiche just as an aside it's hard to read what you write when you boldface three phrases in any sentence. I had to edit all that out of your question before I could really read it.

Comment: @TomateFraiche - Using "step into" can be a bit confusing on any call, not just recursive calls, because it sets the cursor to the same line before the call is made and after the called function returns. If it's after the return, then "step into" will advance to the next line, rather than go into the called function. So with many debuggers, if you're not carefully following the sequence, you may not know if the call was made until you use "step into" again.

Answer (score 0):

Top down merge sort is left first, depth first.
Using | to indicate splitting of array:

```
    |7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0|
    |7 6 5 4|3 2 1 0|
    |7 6|5 4|
    |7|6|
    |6 7|
        |5|4|
        |4 5|
    |4 5 6 7|
            |3 2|1 0|
            |3|2|
            |2 3|
                |1|0|
                |0 1|
            |0 1 2 3|
    |0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7|
```

Bottom up merge sort is breadth first, left first. It skips the
recursive splitting by treating an array of size n to be n runs
of size 1, using iteration to update the indices and run size:

```
    |7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0|
    |7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
    |6 7|
        |4 5|
            |2 3|
                |0 1|
    |4 5 6 7|
            |0 1 2 3|
    |0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7|
```

Comment: A clear illustration. My sort is **top down**. Personally I easily understand the logic of call stack: to return to a statement until it is completely carried out but if I were a machine, I would see no reasons obliging me to return. This is not the case with recursion for example, where machine sees the method invocation in the body of this very method and has to repeat the implementation until the code explicitly tells it to break out. While with call stack it is just necessary **to remember** that later, ''one million'' steps further on, machine will return to your unfinished line(s).

Comment: @TomateFraiche - The call stack is like an array, it saves multiple instances of parameters, return address, and local variables. You could consider the current state of the stack as well as the current instruction as part of the current machine state. Also it doesn't "break out" all at once. In my 8 element top down example, it goes 3 levels deep to merge the |7|6|, returns to 2 levels deep, then goes 3 levels deep to merge |5|4|. Then returns twice to 1 level deep. It repeats this sequence for the right half, then finally returns to caller (0 levels deep) with sorted array.